# Why is react-beautiful-dnd not working correctly?

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-beautiful-dnd

I am using the react-beautiful-dnd library to implement dragging components that are in the same Main component. The code is presented, please help me figure it out. The element is dragged, but does not stay in place, and the elements that are nearby also move

https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-water-tws2i?file=/src/Main.jsx

Comment: Your sandbox is empty / the default app

Comment: @ant is this sandbox working? I can't see any code related to dnd there

Comment: I've already fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try starting your project with npx create-react-app . In the code sample, you aren't rendering anything

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Main />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```